# cannot import name DurationField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to run an application that uses django rest framework.However am getting the import error "cannot import name DurationField".How do i resolve this error ?

Error message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiRl1.png)

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import Http404

from restapp.serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class UserList(APIView):

#List all user,create new one
def get(self,request,format=None):
    users = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(users,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self,request,format=None):
    serializer= UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def delete(self,request,pk, format=None):
    user = self.get_object(pk)
    user.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

class UserDetail(APIView):

#Retrive update,or delete a user instance

def get_object(self,pk):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except user.DoesNotExist:
        raise 404

def get(self,request,pk,format=None):
    user = self.get_object(pk)
    user = UserSerializer(user)
    return Response(user.data)

def put(self,request,pk,format=None):
    user = self.get_object(pk)
    serializer=UserSerializer(user,data = request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


def delete(self,request,pk,format=None):
    user = self.get_object(pk)
    user.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
     model = User
     fields = ('id','username','firstname','last_name','email')
```

It points to this file serializers.py,line 18 as source of error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhy3X.png)

Comment: Where did you use `DurationField` - can't find in the codes.

Comment: It points to a file(serializers.py,line 18 ) that comes with django rest framework.I have added the sceenshot,take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the screenshot, I can see you're using Django 1.7.

The `DurationField` that is being imported by DRF was introduced in Django 1.8.

So you have to upgrade your Django to get this version of DRF to work.